# Allowing external access to bastion hosts on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, cidr

I am trying to create a few bastion hosts in my VPC on aws to connect to my databases that are located in a private subnet. I am using this [aws Quick start](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/linux-bastion/step2.html).

I understand the basics of CIDR blocks and what they mean. However, I don't understand what aws means by the "Allowed Bastion External Access CIDR" parameter. To quote the documentation, this parameter means the following:

"CIDR block that’s allowed SSH external access to the bastion hosts. We recommend that you set this value to a trusted CIDR block. For example, you might want to restrict access to your corporate network."

I don't understand what I should enter in this parameter. Do they want the IP range of my private subnet that will connect to the bastion hosts? Or do they mean by this the range of my private network at home? And does this mean that I can't ssh into my bastion hosts from anywhere else? Obviously I want to restrict access to my bastion hosts, but I don't think I want to only be able to access them from home, since I work from different places and we don't have a private network at the office.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "CIDR block that’s allowed SSH external access to the bastion hosts. We recommend that you set this value to a trusted CIDR block. For example, you might want to restrict access to your corporate network."

At a high level, a more simplistic view of a CIDR block, is that it's an IP address range, expressed in CIDR format, and the guide is essentially telling you to set the IP address range that you want to allow to connect to your Bastion hosts. It's also cautioning you to only set it to a trusted CIDR block, this could be your corporate network, your own IP address, or it could also be the CIDR block range of your private subnet.

If your private subnet CIDR is 10.0.0.0/8 and you set the CIDR block that is allowed to connect to the Bastion to that then you would allow connections to the Bastion from any IP address in the subnet 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255; this is about 16.7m IP's in the subnet that would be allowed to connect; assuming no other inbound rules, only services in the private subnet which have an IP address in that range would be able to connect to the Bastion.  You can specify multiple inbound rules in your security groups which will allow you to connect from different locations, like home or your office, but if you have dynamic IP addresses in those locations you'll need to update your security groups if the IP address changes.

That being said, even though it is a private subnet, and there is no external access, best practice would be to be explicit with the IP addresses that are allowed to connect to your bastion. This increases security, reduces a potential attack surface, and reduces the possibilities of errors.

Comment: Ok so the idea would be to keep my dbs in the private subnet and the bastions in the public one so i could connect to the dbs using the bastions. But to connect to the bastions i should specify my home ip addresses but they are dynamic, so how should i go about that?

Comment: You can update the inbound IP addresses in your security groups as and when needed. You can do this in the Console or via the CLI. This may be inconvenient, especially if you're moving locations regularly, but it is very secure. You could also setup a VPN server (try OpenVPN, available in the AWS Marketplace), and set a static IP for the user you'll use to connect, and then only allow bastion connections from that IP address. Of course, provisioning a box with the VPN server will incur additional costs, so you have to make a choice between that cost and the "inconvenience".

Comment: My pleasure, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

"Allowed Bastion External Access CIDR" parameter - CIDR of host from where you will SSH to your bastion host. I use my laptop's IP in the form of /32 as CIDR to restrict access. If the IP is dynamic, then hephalump's answer is correct, to edit the securty group from AWS console whenever you want to ssh to the bastion host. If you don't want to change security groups then you need other options to have a static IP in home network, like a docker container or a VirtualBox VM which is bridged to your host network.